# Microsoft Excel 365 column totals

Tags: microsoft-excel

Creating a spreadsheet to track quotes.

I have multiple columns of information.

One has the item name, Next is the quantity required for that item, next column has the price of each part.

Each time that I add a price to an item, I want the spreadsheet to total the number of parts (items x quantity) required to quote.

So if there are 30 rows of items, the quantity of each can range from 1 to 5.

There is a total at the bottom for the quantity of items to quote. I want it to update each time a price is put into the price column and multiply the individual quantity that corresponds to that price and giving a total at the bottom.

```
"Required Spare Qty"    "New Quoted Price for Each
1                        $13,815 
2                       0
1                        $17,338 
2                       0
1                        $2,533 
2                       0
2                       0
1                       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A9,B2:B9)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**You can use following Formula to get total number of parts required to be quoted, whenever you add Price to an item.**

[image]

**How it works:**

*I'm assuming that you have Data in Range `A2:C8`.*

- To get Unique part's name write the Array formula in Cell `A12`finish with `Ctrl+Shift+enter` & fill down as many rows you feel *(Keep some extra rows to get New Part's Name).*

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$3:$A$8, MATCH(0, IF($C$3:$C$8>0, COUNTIF($A$11:$A11, $A$3:$A$8), ""), 0)),"")}
  ```
- To get Total numbers of Part's write this Formula in Cell `B12` and fill down *(Keep some extra rows to get new total).*

  ```
  =IF(SUMIF(A3:A8,A12,B3:B8)=0,"",SUMIF(A3:A8,A12,B3:B8))
  ```
- **Additionally**, you can use following Formula to get Price total of the parts need to be quoted in cell `C12` & fill it down *(also keep some extra rows).*

  ```
   =IF(SUMIF(A3:A8,A12,C3:C8)=0,"",SUMIF(A3:A8,A12,C3:C8))
  ```

**Note:**

- **Situation 1** shows summary of two parts **Fan & Glass** for which price has been entered, and **Situation 2** show 3 items since has new entry **Disc's Price**.
- Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.